# How to Create Stored procedure in DB2

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, db2

Can you please help me to create a below Oracle procedure in DB2? Same table name with columns are available in DB2 also but below script is not working

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sample_proc (ACCT_NO in CHAR,p_cursor out SYS_REFCURSOR)
is
BEGIN
 OPEN p_cursor FOR
select sampl1,sample2,sample3
from
table_test b
where
rec_id='A'
and sample3=ACCT_NO ;
END;
```

Comment: Please define "not working".  What error message or behavior do you get?  Also, what do you expect the procedure to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a return better use function here are some example to get collection

```
CREATE TABLE table_test
(
   sample1   VARCHAR2 (1000),
   sample2   VARCHAR2 (1000),
   sample3   VARCHAR2 (1000)
);

insert into table_test ( sample1,sample2 ,sample3)
values     ('daftest1','dsdtest1','sstsest3');  
insert into table_test ( sample1,sample2 ,sample3)
values     ('FAStest1','fstest1','sstsest3');   
insert into table_test ( sample1,sample2 ,sample3)
values     ('sdtest1','asdtest1','fstest3');   
insert into table_test ( sample1,sample2 ,sample3)
values     ('test2','test2','test123');

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST_REC                                                              
AS OBJECT (
   sample1 VARCHAR2(1000)
  ,sample2 VARCHAR2(1000)
  ,sample3 VARCHAR2(1000)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST_REPORT_TABLE                                                              
AS TABLE OF TEST_REC;
```

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testing (p_acct_no IN varchar2)
RETURN test_report_table
IS
 v_rec test_rec;
 v_test_report_table test_report_table := test_report_table();
BEGIN

FOR i IN (SELECT sample1,sample2,sample3
FROM table_test b
--where rec_id='A'
where sample3=p_acct_no)
LOOP
      v_rec:=test_rec(NULL,NULL,NULL);
dbms_output.put_line(i.sample1);

      v_rec.sample1:=i.sample1;
      v_rec.sample2:=i.sample2;
      v_rec.sample3:=i.sample3;
      v_test_report_table.EXTEND;
      v_test_report_table(v_test_report_table.COUNT) :=v_rec;


END LOOP;


RETURN v_test_report_table;




END;

    select * from table(testing(p_acct_no=>'sstsest3'))
```

[image]

Or better use bulk collect if you don't need to add rows dynamically

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION JSTRAUTI.testing (p_acct_no IN varchar2)
RETURN test_report_table
IS
 v_test_report_table test_report_table := test_report_table();


BEGIN

 SELECT test_rec(sample1,sample2,sample3)
 bulk collect into v_test_report_table
FROM table_test b
--where rec_id='A'
where sample3=p_acct_no;

RETURN v_test_report_table;

END;
```

result the same.

Comment: Before you want to get data set returning, you must declare what type of data it will be. there you need to declare/create what types of data will come out.